# Exclude items in an array in unity 2021

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've begun working on an early alpha menu for my game and I've was wondering how to exclude items in an array, specifically in unity. I'm trying to make every item except the currently used one. I don't know how I should go about it, if anyone could help, that would be amazing.

here's my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class CS
{
    public List<GameObject> CanvasButtons;
}
public class CanvasSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public List<CS> Screen = new List<CS>();
    static int switcher;
    public static void ScreenSwitchPlus()
    {
        switcher += 1;
    }
    public static void ScreenSwitchMinus()
    {
        switcher -= 1;
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        
        foreach(GameObject l in Screen[switcher].CanvasButtons)
        {
            l.SetActive(true);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be wiser to use `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop here:

```
public void Update()
{
    int ignore = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < Screen[switcher].CanvasButtons.Count; i++)
    {
        if(i != ignore)
            Screen[switcher].CanvasButtons[i].SetActive(true);
        else
            Screen[switcher].CanvasButtons[i].SetActive(false);
    }        
}
```

It could be even shorter without `if` (admit less readable):

```
public void Update()
{
    int ignore = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < Screen[switcher].CanvasButtons.Count; i++)
    {
        Screen[switcher].CanvasButtons[i].SetActive(i != ignore);
    }        
}
```

... and even shorter with taking CanvasButtons out of loop:

```
public void Update()
{
    int ignore = 2;

    var collection = Screen[switcher].CanvasButtons;

    for(int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
    {
        collection[i].SetActive(i != ignore);
    }        
}
```

Comment: that isn't working well for me. In case you didn't see, my list is actually in two parts. One for the list of buttons, and the other that lists those buttons in what I called `Screen` I wanted the list of buttons in the current screen(sorry if it wasn't obvious, but `switcher` was the current screen in this code) to be active and all other buttons deactivated. I tried other forms of your method to work in my case, but all of them failed.

Comment: the current one being;
`List<CS> csco = Screen;
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < csco.Count;)
        {

            List<GameObject> collection = csco[i1].CanvasButtons;
            for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
            {
                collection[i].SetActive(i != switcher);
            }
            switch(csco[i1].CanvasButtons == csco[csco.Count].CanvasButtons)
            {
                case true:
                    i1++;
                    break;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I was a bit null-brained for a while there, I messed up a few values in the second for statement, but I got it. I'll post the code here. I keep forgetting little things in the math. Like I always say, I don't solve problems, I make them.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class CS
{
    public List<GameObject> CanvasButtons;
}
public class CanvasSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<CS> Screen = new List<CS>();
    static int switcher;
    public static void ScreenSwitchPlus()
    {
        switcher += 1;
    }
    public static void ScreenSwitchMinus()
    {
        switcher -= 1;
    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        List<CS> csco = Screen;
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < csco.Count;)
        {

            List<GameObject> collection = csco[i1].CanvasButtons;
            for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
            {
                collection[i].SetActive(i1 == switcher);
                switch(i == collection.Count - 1)
                {
                    case true:
                        i1++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly is that `switch` for? it is true only for the very last item ... so .. just let your inner `for` loop run to end and rather put the `i1++` at the end of the outer for loop ...

Comment: and you really shouldn't do this in `Update` each and every frame at all ... do it event driven the moment the `switcher` is actually changed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making things too complicated.

It could simply be

```
public void Update()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < Screen.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach(var button in Screen[i].CanvasButtons)
        {
            button.SetActive(i == switcher);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Two more points though.

First I would make sure that `switcher` is actually a valid value. You either want to clamp the value to stay within the index range like

```
public static void ScreenSwitchPlus()
{
    switcher = Mathf.Clamp(switcher + 1, 0, Screen.Count);
}

public static void ScreenSwitchMinus()
{
    switcher = Mathf.Clamp(switcher - 1, 0, Screen.Count);
}
```

or you could implement wrap around at the ends according to your needs like

```
public static void ScreenSwitchPlus()
{
    switcher = (switcher + 1) % Screen.Count;
}

public static void ScreenSwitchMinus()
{
    switcher -= 1;
    if(switcher < 0) switcher = Screen.Count - 1;
}
```

and then finally as mentioned I wouldn't do this poll fetching the value in `Update` **every frame** at all but rather event driven.

If you really need to (I would claim it is just lazyness ;) ) have that value and methods `static` you could attach to an event like

```
private static event Action<int> OnSwitcherChanged;

public static void ScreenSwitchPlus()
{
    switcher = (switcher + 1) % Screen.Count;

    OnSwitcherChanged?.Invoke(switcher);
}

public static void ScreenSwitchMinus()
{
    switcher -= 1;
    if(switcher < 0) switcher = Screen.Count - 1;

    OnSwitcherChanged?.Invoke(switcher);
}
```

and then listen to that event like

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    OnSwitcherChanged += HandleSwitchChanged;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    OnSwitcherChanged -= HandleSwitchChanged;
}

private void HandleSwitchChanged(int newIndex)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < Screen.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach(var button in Screen[i].CanvasButtons)
        {
            button.SetActive(i == switcher);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class CS {
    public List<GameObject> CanvasButtons;
}
public class CanvasSwitcher : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<CS> Screen = new List<CS>();

    private static bool m_changed = false;
    private static int m_lastSwitcher = 0;
    private static int m_switcher = 0;
    static int switcher {
        get {
            return m_switcher;
        }
        set {
            if ( switcher != value ) {
                m_lastSwitcher = m_switcher;
                m_changed = true;
                m_switcher = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void ScreenSwitchPlus() {
        switcher += 1;
    }
    public static void ScreenSwitchMinus() {
        switcher -= 1;
    }

    private void Update() {
        if ( m_changed ) {
            UpdateCS();
            m_changed = false;
        }
    }

    void UpdateCS() {
        if ( m_lastSwitcher < Screen.Count ) {
            var canvasBtns = Screen[ m_lastSwitcher ].CanvasButtons;
            for ( int i = 0; i < canvasBtns.Count; i++ ) {
                canvasBtns[ i ].SetActive( false );
            }
        }
        if ( switcher < Screen.Count ) {
            var canvasBtns = Screen[ switcher ].CanvasButtons;
            for ( int i = 0; i < canvasBtns.Count; i++ ) {
                canvasBtns[ i ].SetActive( true );
            }
        }
    }
}
```